# Access to a process in procfs by name from bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, process, proc

I want access to the status.log file of some processes, from bash terminal, in a while loop and compare them. So since the PID are not static how can I gain access to their proc/PID files with their command names and not with PID?

Answer (score 0):

Try to grep output from `ps -A` by name of the command and get PID from there

Comment: Yeah but after this how can i use the PIDs without any input of the user? I mean i wanna each time to find the PIDs by name and them use them to reach the processes status

Comment: you can trim output from grep and save PID to variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

**Example:**

```
sleep 1000 &
cd  /proc/`pidof sleep`
```

Refer this link [man pidof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof)

Comment: Your example only works if a single process called `sleep` exists (you should probably call `pidof` with the `-s` option so it returns a single PID in this case)

Comment: @Hasturkun,`cd` command only take the first argument ignore other arguments .

Comment: @KalanidhiM. And what if the lowest numbered `sleep` process is the wrong one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `pgrep` (which you should, it's part of procps), call `pgrep -x somecmdname`  to get a list of PIDs matching that string. From there you can access the proc files as usual.

e.g.

```
for pid in `pgrep -x somecmd`; do
echo $pid #or do something more interesting
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the command `pidof`:

```
$ pidof bash
14317 10465 7204 3514 3466
```

Then you can loop over the pids:

```
$ for pid in $(pidof bash); do echo "$pid" ; done
14317
10465
7204
3514
3466
```